# me sale este error System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: al ejecutar mi api en net core

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, net

Actualmente tengo un problema al ejecutar mi api de net core 6.0 y que hice merge mediante git con respecto a otras ramas y aparecio este problema al tratar de ejecutar de nuevo mi proyecto y me gustaria saber a que se puede deber el error que sale es el siguiente:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'La dirección solicitada no es válida en este contexto.'
```

y sale en la siguiente linea:

```
app.Run();
```

Y el detalle del error es el siguiente:

```
Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, string)
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Net.Internals.SocketAddress)
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(System.Net.EndPoint)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(System.Net.EndPoint)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(System.Net.EndPoint, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionDelegate, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.EndpointConfig, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo por ahí, estás tratando de abrir un puerto (un `TcpListener`?) indicando una dirección que no está asignada a una interfaz de red del equipo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889972/the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context-when-i-try-to-listen-a-port